# How to realize drag and drop pin like in windows 8 maps application

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, windows-store-apps, bing-maps

In windows 8(.1)'s maps application, it allows adding a pin by clicking and dragging a pin. When I click on the pin in the below bar, a new pin will be created and could be moved by mouse without releasing the mouse clicking. I am trying to realize the same manipulation but I don't know how.

I have tried to move a custom pin between two grids, but when the mouse moved from first grid to the second one, the focus on pin is lost, then the event OnMouseMove can't be entered.

I use C#/XAML and BingMap API.
Any help will be appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution, using UIElement.CapturePointer() would help to change to the MapView after clicked add a new pin. Like below. Hope that will help any one with the same problem.

```
private void PinPointerPressed(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (BottomAppBar != null) BottomAppBar.IsOpen = false;
        MapView.CapturePointer(e.Pointer);
        ...
    }
```

Then, all registered pointer events of MapView could be triggered